# Java: Arrays/methods: Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arrays, methods

`TERADENWOORDEN` is the array with [0][0] = book and [0][1] = lord of the rings

`CATEGORIES` = amount of categories

`geefNamenCat` is a method that returns an `input.readString()` to `gekozenCat`

am I doing something wrong here?

```
public void catKiezen() {
   boolean bevatGekozen = false;
   String gekozenCat
    do {
        gekozenCat = geefNamenCat();
        for (String[] TeradenwoordenLijst : Arrays.asList(TERADENWOORDEN))
            if (Arrays.asList(TeradenwoordenLijst).contains(gekozenCat)) {
                bevatGekozen = true;
                break;
            }
        if (! bevatGekozen) {
            System.out.println("De opgegeven categorie is ongeldig.");
        }
    } while (! bevatGekozen);
   String woordVanCat = woordBepalen (gekozenCat);
}

public String woordBepalen(String teBepalenWoordVanCat) {
    for (int p = 0; p < CATEGORIES; p++)
       if (TERADENWOORDEN[p][0].equals(teBepalenWoordVanCat))
       return TERADENWOORDEN[p][1];
}
```

in the end i get an error `cannot find symbol` for the line `String woordVanCat = woordBepalen (gekozenCat);`

update:

I am now getting a 'missing return statement'

```
public String woordBepalen(String teBepalenWoordVanCat) {
    for (int p = 0; p < CATEGORIES; p++) {
        if (TERADENWOORDEN[p][0].equals(teBepalenWoordVanCat)) {
        return TERADENWOORDEN[p][1];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I can see your method `woordBepalen` does not compile, because the compiler is not sure that it has a well-defined value to return

```
public String woordBepalen(String teBepalenWoordVanCat) {
    for (int p = 0; p < CATEGORIES; p++)
       if (TERADENWOORDEN[p][0].equals(teBepalenWoordVanCat))
       return TERADENWOORDEN[p][1];
}
```

EDIT

You'll have to define what do return in case for no `p` `TERADENWOORDEN[p][0].equals(teBepalenWoordVanCat)` holds. Like this:

```
 public String woordBepalen(String teBepalenWoordVanCat) {
        for (int p = 0; p < CATEGORIES; p++) {
           if (TERADENWOORDEN[p][0].equals(teBepalenWoordVanCat))
             return TERADENWOORDEN[p][1];
        }
        return null;
 }
```

It's up to you to decide if returning `null` is the right thing to do. Another possibility is throwing an exception

Comment: Sjuan76 predicting the future. Some simple fix for this too then I guess?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much guys. I would upvote if I could but i need 4 more rep ;p

Answer (score 5):

you have declared `String gekozenCat = geefNamenCat();` inside your do-while and trying to access it outside the loop.`gekozenCat` is only **confined** with-in your `do-while`. declared it outside `do-while` if you want to access it outside your do-while.

Comment: Why don't you try to compile it?

Comment: Alright so that did indeed do the trick, I feel dumb now. Anyway it gave me a new error. Missing return statement. I guess this is because the return is inside the loop too? I have updated the original post

Comment: @Jente absolutely, check gefei answer. he mentioned it in his answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. Was superfast too! :)

Answer (score 1):

The scope of `gekozenCat` is inside the `do..while` block. Outside that block, you have not defined it so that causes the error.

In general, if you have a block `{` `}`, variables defined inside that block will only be available inside that block (and after they have been defined).